# How to select checkboxes with same web elements in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to write an automated script for an E2E testing using protractor + Jasmine. But, struck at a point of selecting a checkbox where all the web elements are same for all three checkboxes. I want to select the second checkbox.

Could anyone guide me through this issue please ? Below is the Angular JS code snippet for your kind reference.

Even the xpath and CSSSelector value wasn't helpful since they were same as well.

CSSSelector: #checks
xpath: //*[@id="checks"]

The only tag which I see the difference in this is [class="ng-binding"].

Snippet:

```
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
<td>
<input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">
Product1
</td>
</tr>
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
<td>
<input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">
Product2
</td>
</tr>
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
<td>
<input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">
Product3
</td>
</tr>
```

Cheers,
Ashish

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same ID in one HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tony mentioned in the comment that you cannot have more than one element with same `id` in DOM.
Ideally you need to fix that.

Now lets assume that its **not** in your hands to get that corrected, you can still use below selector to select second checkbox

`element.all(by.css(input[name="checks"]))[1]`
or
`element.all(by.css(input[name="checks"])).get(1)`

Please check which one is working for you.

Comment: Hi Ashish - Thanks. The later option has worked fine.
element.all(by.css('input[name="checks"]')).get(1).click(); //works fine.
//element.all(by.css('input[name="checks"]'))[1].click();  //Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined.

I have also asked the corresponding dev team to change the IDs as suggested by Tony. For now, I'm progressing with element.all(by.css('input[name="checks"]')).get(1)

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change IDs to distinguish your checks

```
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
    <td>
    <input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks-0-{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
    Product1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
    <td>
    <input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks-1-{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
    Product2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr x-ng-repeat="productOffering in allProductList" class="prod-input-select ng-scope">
    <td>
    <input ng-show="productOffering.added == 'N'" name="checks" id="checks-2-{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-click="addTempProductToBeAdded($event,productOffering)" ng-model="productOffering.isSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">
    Product3
    </td>
</tr>
```

And maybe you could try using the **startsWith** selector

CSSSelector: `[id^="checks"]`

xpath: `//*[starts-with(@id,'checks')][@type="checkbox" and (@checked)]`

Comment: For now I have identified the element using xpath which gives me an array and the warning say's '[13:44:26] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, //*[@id="checks"]) - the first result will be used'. And I could see the first check box is being selected. Does it mean I could select the second from the array list and invoke click function ? if yes, how could I do the same ? I'm not sure as I'm pretty new to Protractor & Jasmine.

Comment: Could you try using `[id^="checks"]:checked` ?

Comment: Hi Tony -  element(by.xpath('//*[id^="checks"]')).click(); Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[id^="checks"] because of the following error:
 //SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[id^="checks"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Tony - I have asked the dev team to change the IDs as suggested by you. For now, I'm progressing with element.all(by.css('input[name="checks"]')).get(1).

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: I found this (sorry I was at lunch) `//*[starts-with(@id,'checks')][@type="checkbox" and (@checked)]`